# How to get all nodes in a disjointed sub-graph - neo4j / py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

If I have a neo4j database and I want to query to get all nodes that are in a one specific disjointed sub-graph. (in py2neo or in cypher)

If I have groups of nodes, the nodes in each group are connected by relationship within that group, but are not connects between groups. Can I query for one node and get all the nodes in that node's group?

Comment: Are you looking for connected components? How does you graph model look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

## Original Answer

If by "group of nodes" you mean a "disjoint subgraph", here is how you can get all the nodes in the disjoint subgraph (with relationships of any type) that contains a specific node (say, the `Neo` node):

```
MATCH (n { name: "Neo" })
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(n)-[*]-(m)
RETURN REDUCE(s = [n], x IN COLLECT(NODES(p)) |
  REDUCE(t = s, y IN x | CASE WHEN y IN t THEN t ELSE t + y END )) AS nodes;
```

This query uses an `OPTIONAL MATCH` to find the nodes "related" to the `Neo` node, so that if that node has no relationships, the query would still be able to return a result.

The two (nested) `REDUCE` clauses make sure that the returned collection only has distinct nodes.

The outer `REDUCE` clause initialized the result collection with the `n` node, since it must always be in the disjoint subgraph, even if there are no other nodes.

## Better Answer

```
MATCH p=(n { name: "Neo" })-[r*0..]-(m)
WITH NODES(p) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
RETURN DISTINCT node
```

This simpler query (which returns node rows) uses `[r*0..]` to allow 0-length paths (i.e., `n` does not need to have any relationships -- and `m` can be the same as `n`). It uses `UNWIND` to turn the `nodes` node collection(s) into rows, and then uses `DISTINCT` to eliminate duplicates.

## Alternate Solution (does not work yet, due to bug)

This alternate solution below (which returns node rows) should also have worked, except that there is currently a bug ([that I just reported](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5851)) that causes all identifiers to be forgotten after a query unwinds a `NULL` (which can happen, for instance, if an `OPTIONAL MATCH` fails to find a match). Due to this bug, if the `Neo` node has no relationships, the query below currently returns no results. Therefore, you have to use the query above until the bug is fixed.

```
MATCH (n { name: "Neo" })
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(n)-[*]-(m)
WITH n, NODES(p) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
RETURN DISTINCT (
  CASE
  WHEN node IS NULL THEN n
  ELSE node END ) AS res;
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you added a diagram or some sample data. However, if I'm understanding your data model correctly you are defining "groups" of nodes as all nodes connected by a certain relationship? So to get all members of "group1" nodes (let's define that as all nodes connected by a group1 relationship) and not any nodes connected to group2 you could use a query like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:GROUP1]-(b:Person)
WHERE NOT exists((a)-[:GROUP2]-())
RETURN a
```

You can also use [Node labels](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-create.html#create-create-a-node-with-a-label) to define groups of Nodes.